# PHP File Upload Undefined Index error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I'm extremely confused by this. I have a form in which a user has the option to upload a resume... easy enough.

Unfortunately, every time I try to validate the file, I keep getting an 'Undefined Index' error, meaning the `$_FILES[]` array is empty. I have upped my `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` and ensured file uploads were turned on in my php.ini file and restarted apache but still the array returns empty.

Here is my form HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="/includes/mail/" method="post">
    <div id="resume-input" class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Upload Resume</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" name="resume" id="resume-file" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is the PHP checking for the file:

```
if(!isset($_FILES['resume'])) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Please upload your resume.</span><br />";
    return false;
} else {
    // Validate uploaded file
    $fileName = $_FILES['resume']['name']; // file name
    $fileExt = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1); // file extension
    $fileSize = $_FILES['resume']['size']/1024; // size in KBs
    $filePath = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_path']; // file path
}
```

Obviously this isn't the entire script, but this is the only part that doesn't work. I have tried `var_dump($_FILES);` at the beginning of the script and that returns `array(0) { }`

Can anyone see from what I have posted why this file upload isn't working?

**PS:** The form is being submitted via jQuery AJAX. I don't know if it's necessary or not, but here is that AJAX submit:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: contactForm.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data) {
        returnMsg.fadeIn();
        returnMsg.html(data); // show response from the php script.
        if(data.indexOf("success") + 1) {
            $('form#contact-form input[type="text"],input[type="email"],textarea').val('');
            $('form#contact-form select[name="subject"]').val('Select a subject');
        } 

    }
});
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: [click here][1] to see the answer ... ...... .....


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Check `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`, make sure it says `POST`. If it says `GET`, then you've got a full-blown HTTP redirect occuring and landing on your upload script as a GET request, meaning the upload is lost. Becase as written right now, your html looks fine, and your php should be working. Plus, you cannot upload files through standard AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're uploading it. `data: contactForm.serialize()` just won't work with files. You've got the correct form, but by replacing it with a jQuery AJAX request, you completely change the request.

It is possible to use AJAX to upload files in HTML5, and you don't need the form:

```
document.querySelector('#resume-file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("resume", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            // success!!!
        }
    }

    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

For more information see: [MDN - Using FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

EDIT:

Here's how to do it in jQuery too (taken from MDN docs):

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
  url: "stash.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I wasn't aware we couldn't upload files via jQuery AJAX

Comment: No problem. It is actually possible to do it in jQuery, just with slightly different options. It explains how in the link I posted, but I'll reference it in the answer too. Cheers.

Comment: One of the biggest advantages to doing it using the XMLHTTPRequest object is the ability to listen to upload progress events, which allows you to have a progress bar.